# How to call c# function without semicolon?

Tags: c#, function, methods

I am a beginner to c#, Can any one help me with following question from last interview

> Is it possible to call a c# function without semicolon ?

Usually we call c# function like

```
FunctionName();
```

How can we call functions without semicolon ?

Comment: In c# ,it calls method. semicolon is belong to a statement. within the statement you can call many method.

Comment: That's a terrible question for an interview, to be honest.

Comment: @Rob yes it was :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can call c# function without semicolon and I am sure you must be done this before.

suppose you have two functions like below

```
string GetString()
{
    return "Message";
}

bool Validation(int i)
{
    if (i != 0)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

You can call these function like

```
MessageBox.Show(GetString());

if (Validation(5))
{
    //do somthing here
}
```